# Sequential or batch parameters estimation

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, supervised-learning

[image]

This is the problem that I should describe. Unfortunately the only one technique that I studied to estimate the parameters in the linear regression is the classic **gradient descent algorithm**. Is that one of "batch" or "sequential" mode ? And what is the difference between them ?

Comment: In gradient descent, for every iteration of the algorithm each parameter is adjusted with the assumption that [change in parameter value / change in target error value] is linear, so a fixed "step size" is used to try and prevent changing the parameter's value too much (overshoot) or too little (slow). In Levenberg-Marquardt, the calculation of "step size" is effectively automatic, as the relationship between parameter value change and error value change is assumed to be *quadratic* and the minimum value of that quadratic relationship is used in each step. That's how I understand it.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks for the explanation , so I should say that the gradient descent is sequential right ? While the Levenberg-Marquardt is a batch method ?

Comment: Both are iterative, and the language used is as if you take a step towards a goal and look around before taking another step. In each iteration, the parameters are changed (the "step") in a direction that reduces model error. The major difference in the two methods is the determination of step size. In my understanding, the term sequential" is less accurate than the more common term "iterative", while the term "batch" is not used for these methods. In these fitting methods, we are repeatedly taking a step towards a lower error solution and then again changing the parameters.

Comment: Ok I understood , do you know any batch method that I can read about ? I’ve never heard the term “batch” to describe a parameter estimation method

Comment: A batch method would be something like a "function finder" or "equation search" where large numbers of equations are fitted to the same data set and the resulting fits  ranked by some fit statistic. There are several programs and web sites - including my site zunzun.com - that can do this, and as the individual fits are independent they can be performed in parallel for performance if multiple CPUs are available. As the batch technique can produce overfitting, such as "Runge's phenomenon" in higher-order polynomials, care must be taken when applying the technique.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't expecting to find exactly the question from the ML exam here! Well the point is that as James Phillips says the gradient descent is an iterative method, so called sequential. The gradient descent is just an iterative optimization algorithm for finding the minimum of a function but you could use it to find the 'best-fitting line'. A complete batch way will be e.g. the Linear Least Squares method applying all the equations at once. You can find all the parameters calculating the partial derivatives of the sum of the square of the errors w.r.t. the best line fit and setting them to zero. Of course, as Phillips said it is not a convenient method, it's more a theoretical definition. Hope, it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

From Liang et al. ["*A Fast and Accurate Online Sequential Learning Algorithm for Feedforward Networks*"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.217.1418&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> ***Batch learning*** is usually a time consuming affair as it may involve many iterations through the training data. In most applications, this may take several minutes to several hours and further the learning parameters (i.e., learning rate, number of learning epochs, stopping criteria, and other predefined parameters) must be properly chosen to ensure convergence. Also, whenever a new data is received batch learning uses the past data together with the new data and performs a retraining, thus consuming a lot of time. There are many industrial applications where online ***sequential*** learning algorithms are preferred over ***batch*** learning algorithms as ***sequential*** learning algorithms do not require retraining whenever a new data is received. The *back-propagation (BP)* algorithm and its variants have been the backbone for training SLFNs with additive hidden nodes. It is to be noted that BP **is basically a *batch* learning algorithm**. *Stochastic gradient descent BP (SGBP)* is one of the main variants of BP for ***sequential*** learning applications.

Basically, gradient descent is theorized in a batch way, but in practice you use iterative methods.

I think the question doesn't ask you to show two ways (batch *and* sequential) to estimate the parameters of the model, but instead to explain—either in a batch *or* sequential mode—how such an estimation would work.

For instance, if you are trying to estimate parameters for a linear regression model, you could just describe likelihood maximization, which is equivalent to minimize the least square error:

[image: Least square error minimization formula]

If you want to show a sequential mode, you can describe the gradient descent algorithm.